# Rear Disk Brake Jamming Issue - Royal Enfield Thunderbird 350

Tags: motorcycle, royal-enfield, disk-brakes, thunderbird

From the last few days, I am having this issue wherein my rear disk brakes are getting jammed and the brake-pads do not disengage.

The bike does not move and the disk plate get red hot. I have keep it for some time to cool down after which the bike can be moved again. I will take the bike to the service center soon.

I would like to know the reasons for the same and also what could be the solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: This is a rampant issue with this motorcycle model , the design is inherently flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

1) the pads are sticking in the caliper - possibly corrosion or dirt

2) the pistons are sticking / seized in the caliper

Whichever, this needs investigating and correcting - pads sticking will be less expensive...

Comment: The issue was the second one. I changed the whole rear brake assembly and now everything works like a charm.

Comment: @NamanSharma well done, good luck.